# JavaScript google gapi spreadsheets.create not setting title, using 'Untitled speadsheet'

Tags: javascript, google-api-js-client

When I use the following, the sheet is created, but the title isn't being set.

When I use the api explorer, it creates with the right title. Using this documentation: 
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create?apix_params=%7B%22resource%22%3A%7B%22properties%22%3A%7B%22title%22%3A%22x%22%7D%7D%7D

```
var request = gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.create({ "properties": { "title": "x" } }, {});
```

in the response:

```
... 
title: "Untitled spreadsheet"
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var request = gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.create({ "properties": { "title": "x" } });
```

Removing the second object was all I needed.